# DIV with display: inline-block containing image and text does not shrink-to-fit correctly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

While trying to create a responsive menu I've stumbled upon the following problem. If a div contains an image and text and this div has either `display: inline-block` or `float: left` this div's width will be less than the content's width in [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SX73v.png).
In Chrome everything looks good. Here's [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ukbu9gvk/1/).
So the question is: is it possible to somehow fix the content bleed out of menu items in Firefox? Maybe there's some other solution as to how one can size variable width images to 100% height in menu items such as in my jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 solutions for your case:

1. Quick:

   - change `display: inline-block;` to `display: inline;`. It seems to act like you wanted in both Chrome and Firefox.
2. Not so quick:

   - implement the [clearfix workaround](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)
3. Revised answer: https://jsfiddle.net/ukbu9gvk/2/

Comment: 1. I need menu items to have 100% height of their parent so that won't do. 2. Clearfix doesn't seem to do anything in this case.

Comment: Please see solution #3, maybe that helps. I just played with the padding of the name.

Comment: Well the padding of the menu item name seems to be irrelevant. But the interesting thing is that the menu item having `display: inline` and `height: 100%` somehow passes the calculated height value from its parent to its child image which also has `height: 100%` which in turn stretches menu item's height to 100% of its parent's height which is what I need. And I thought that setting any height on inline elements is a waste of bytes. I'll accept your answer after some time if no one gives a less _shady_ answer.

Comment: Huh, looks like removing `height: 100%` from inline menu items still allows for child images to have the needed height. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered, but I cannot comment and thought the OP could use some clarification, considering his surprise that the solution would work.

Reading how [the height property](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visudet.html#the-height-property) works, we see that, in the case of percentage heights:

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block.

What qualifies as "the generated box's containing block" is explained [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/containingblock).

In this case, the image's containing block is in fact the *footer-menu* div, because the image's direct parent (the *menu-item* div) is set to "inline". Hence, the image's height is calculated with respect to the height of the *footer-menu* div.

Hope that helps.